# Looping over jest tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to loop over tests in Jest like this:

```
describe('Test <ChartWidget /> structure in other views.', () => {

const buttonsText = ["Totals per month", "Totals per year", "Values per month"];


buttonsText.forEach( (text) => {
    const button = mountedChartWidget.find('button').findWhere(button => button.text()===text);
    button.simulate('click');    

    it('has correct header', () => {
        expect(mountedChartWidget.contains(
            <header>
                <h1>DATA CHART</h1>
                <h2>{text}</h2>
                <p>Use the buttons and filters below to display different data for different countries or years.</p>
            </header>
        )).toEqual(true);            
    });
)};
```

I found several threads saying that this is possible, except it fails miserably every time, and as I found out, it is because the 'it' blocks are all executed right away. (I figured it out by adding console.log(text) before the 'it' block, and the console showed that the values of 'text' were all logged correctly before the three 'it' blocks were executed, so that the final result was three 'it' blocks executed after 'text' already been assigned its final value.

Does anyone know how do I correctly implement a loop like this? Is there any way I can delay the execution of the 'it' block so that it won't run before 'text' has the correct value?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to add the text to the test description: `it('has correct header for: ' + text , () `. In your case jest has a problem with test with the same name.

Comment: No, I didn't, but I was suggested a different approach -rather than having different it blocks inside the loop, I have a loop inside all the it blocks. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for the future. :)

Comment: There is a feature in jest test.each it might help https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtable-name-fn-timeout